# IOS: AOT ahead of time, what is it?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have read an article from Xamarin, and came across a particular computer science word : Ahead of Time.
According to some google search result, this AOT does not allow for code generation during run time.
Does it mean, it does not support dynamic stuff?

I know this question may stupid and I have 0 knowledge in IOS, hopefully can get some answer from here. thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, what is the definition of dynamic? For the general public, dynamic code mean the application can change functionality at run-time.  For the iOS platform, the binaries are signed to prevent malware.  And Apple don't like apps that can load functionality at run-time.

An **[ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler)** has nothing to do with dynamic code per se. It's has to do with  intermediate language that are **[just-in-time compilation (JIT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)**. The biggest example of intermediate language is Java bytecode; compile once, run anywhere.  When a Java application is executing, the compiled code is JIT to native machine code. AOT compiler is just doing it ahead of time, to save time.

For the iOS platform, Xcode compiles Objective-C to a native binary for the device.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of looking at this is with an example...

In .Net, you can use the [Reflection.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50(v=vs.100).aspx) namespace to generate and compile code at runtime.

Eg you could create an "IDE" with a textbox that accepts C#. When you click a button that C# could be compiled by the .Net framework into a custom library that's loaded dynamically or a fully-fledged executable which is launched as a new process.

This is insanely powerful when combined with the rest of the System.Reflection namespace. You can examine objects at runtime and compile custom code based on any criteria you like.

That said... The problems usually outweigh the benefits in most cases. Mainly, it's a massive security issue, especially when running on a consumer device.

It would be possible to create an app that wouldn't have anything close to malicious code, get it audited by apple, then have the app download code from your webserver, compile it, and execute it. This new code wouldn't be audited...

There really is no good reason to be doing this in a consumer app.